# Does bagging use all the data?

Tags: bagging

When using [Bootstrap Aggregating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating) (known as bagging), does all of the data get used, or is it possible for some of the data never to make it into the bagging samples and thereby getting excluded from whatever statistical procedure that is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have some data $\{(y_i, x_i)\}$ with $i=1,\ldots,n$. A bootstrap sample is when you sample from the data above with replacement, and your sample is the same size as your original data set.

On an individual bootstrap sample, let's call it $(y^*_i,x^*_i), i=1,\ldots n$, the number of times a certain row of data shows up is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $1/n$. The probability it does not show up in ONE bootstrap sample is $(n-1)/n$. Let's call that number $\theta$. Then if you have $B$ bootstrap samples, and you use independence, you get the probability of a row of data never being used in ANY of the $B$ samples to be $\theta^B$.

To answer your question, there is always some probability that a row of data does not get used. But this probability gets very small when you increase $B$.

Comment: So does all the data have to get used....?

Comment: @RustyStatistician.  You use sampling with replacement.  There is a chance that some observations never fall into boosted sample.

Comment: @StatsStudent thanks!  That's all I wanted to know.

Comment: Note that limit (1-1/n)^n as n->infinity = 1/e . Hence, for a large dataset of n items, if you sample as it size you will get ~ 36%

Comment: @Dan Levin - it sounds like a fair "heuristic" is to have  at least 4x more in the total bootstrap sampling than in the sample in order to avoid missing one.  Is that correct?

Comment: The more rounds you'll take the lower will be the probability not to miss any sample. However, I'm not sure this direction is useful. First, the more rounds you'll do the more samples will appear more than once, giving them different weights. More important, bootstrapping is meant to work on different dataset from the original one. You are meant to generate few datasets, train a classifier on each dataset and use the ensemble of classifiers to predict. By generating the different datasets you make the classifier predict a bit differently and improve your overall stability.

Comment: Yeah, $B$ shouldn't depend on this probability. You're probably after better predictions. That's a different question @EngrStudent